# how to fetch a value through session in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

I am undergoing a very strange problem.
I have a dropdown on the First page so i select a value from the dropdown and click a button.
On click i move to another page so on that page i use this and fetch the selected value from the dropdown on first page:

```
 int hobbyid = Convert.ToInt32(formcollection["Hobby"]);
```

Now the problem is the new page comes under tabs.
so on click of button on first page it moves to this tab but if i go to some other page and then come bck to this page by clicking on its tab.now the formcollection method does not yield me any value.how should i resolve this?
Can i resolve this using session?
But i dont know how to use it.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the hobby thougut the navigation, you have to keep it somewhere. One way is to keep in the querystrings. ie : when you move to the first tab, pass the hobbyid as part of the qyerystring and there you read it and set as the qyerystring part of all relevant links (that points to the page where you want the hobbyid)in that page as well. Then you should read the value from the querystring if the formcollection["hobby"] is null.

Another way is to use session. So whenever use selects an item from dropdwon and submit, Set it on a session variable and access it from there.

```
Session["selectedHobby"]="some value read from the form";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.net TempData.

TempData is available only for a user’s session and it persists only till we have read it and then it gets cleared at the end of the request. One can use TempData When data needs to persist between two requests or a redirect scenario.

Store:

```
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult MyAction(UserInfo user) {


   TempData["Hobby"] = User.Hobby;//In USerInfo view model Hobby property is of type string or int depends on what you need)

 return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

Retrive it in the view:

```
<div>
 @if (TempData["Hobby"] != null) {

 <p>Hobby: @TempData["Hobby"]</p>

 }
</div>
```